# C memory management error?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

This is my C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef struct _Frag
{
  struct _Frag *next;
  char *seq;
  int x1;
  int length;
} Frag;

typedef struct _Fragment
{
  int type;
  Frag *frag_list;
} Fragment;

static void
free_frags (Fragment * frags, int len)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      Fragment *fragment = &frags[i];
      Frag *current = fragment->frag_list;

      while (current != NULL)
    {
      free (current->seq);
      fragment->frag_list = current->next;
      free (current);
      current = fragment->frag_list;
    }

      /* to do : free fragment */
      free (fragment);
      fragment = NULL;
    }
  free (frags);
}

int
main ()
{
  Fragment *frags = (Fragment *) malloc (10 * sizeof (Fragment));
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      Fragment *fragment = &frags[i];
      fragment->frag_list = (Frag *) malloc (1 * sizeof (Frag));
      Frag *frag = fragment->frag_list;
      frag->seq = malloc (6 * sizeof (char));
      strcpy (frag->seq, "55555");
      frag->next = (Frag *) malloc (1 * sizeof (Frag));
      frag = frag->next;
      frag->seq = malloc (6 * sizeof (char));
      strcpy (frag->seq, "55555");
      frag->next=NULL;
    }
  free_frags (frags, 10);
  return 0;
}
```

when I debug it with gdb, the error message is :

```
(gdb) run a.out 
..........................
..........................
09574000-09595000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7e00000-b7e21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
b7e21000-b7f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7f2e000-b7f4b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 298454     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7f4b000-b7f4c000 rwxp 0001c000 08:08 298454     /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
b7f4c000-b7f4d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
b7f4d000-b808d000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 67152259   /lib/libc-2.10.1.so
b808d000-b808f000 r-xp 0013f000 08:08 67152259   /lib/libc-2.10.1.so
b808f000-b8090000 rwxp 00141000 08:08 67152259   /lib/libc-2.10.1.so
b8090000-b8094000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
b80ae000-b80af000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b80af000-b80cb000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 67152744   /lib/ld-2.10.1.so
b80cb000-b80cc000 r-xp 0001b000 08:08 67152744   /lib/ld-2.10.1.so
b80cc000-b80cd000 rwxp 0001c000 08:08 67152744   /lib/ld-2.10.1.so
bfc0f000-bfc24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb80ae424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) where
#0  0xb80ae424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7f77411 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7f78c12 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7fb271d in __libc_message () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0xb7fb8581 in malloc_printerr () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0xb7fb9c82 in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0xb7fbcd4d in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x08048488 in free_frags (frags=0x9574008, len=10) at main.c:41
#8  0x080485b3 in main () at main.c:65
(gdb)
```

The valgrind message is as following:

```
==2832== Memcheck, a memory error detector.
==2832== Copyright (C) 2002-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2832== Using LibVEX rev 1884, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==2832== Copyright (C) 2004-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==2832== Using valgrind-3.4.1, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==2832== Copyright (C) 2000-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2832== For more details, rerun with: -v
==2832== 
==2832== Invalid read of size 4
==2832==    at 0x8048442: free_frags (main.c:31)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832==  Address 0x418b034 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 80 free'd
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x8048487: free_frags (main.c:42)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832== 
==2832== Invalid write of size 4
==2832==    at 0x8048460: free_frags (main.c:36)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832==  Address 0x418b034 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 80 free'd
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x8048487: free_frags (main.c:42)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832== 
==2832== Invalid read of size 4
==2832==    at 0x8048471: free_frags (main.c:38)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832==  Address 0x418b034 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 80 free'd
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x8048487: free_frags (main.c:42)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832== 
==2832== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x8048487: free_frags (main.c:42)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832==  Address 0x418b030 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 80 free'd
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x8048487: free_frags (main.c:42)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832== 
==2832== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x80484A5: free_frags (main.c:45)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832==  Address 0x418b028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 80 free'd
==2832==    at 0x4023EBA: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/x86-linux/vgpreload_memcheck.so)
==2832==    by 0x8048487: free_frags (main.c:42)
==2832==    by 0x80485B2: main (main.c:66)
==2832== 
==2832== ERROR SUMMARY: 55 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 1)
==2832== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==2832== malloc/free: 41 allocs, 51 frees, 520 bytes allocated.
==2832== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==2832== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.
```

Please help me to fix them, thanks.

Comment: Try to use Valgrind's Memcheck - it will show you where you fail.

Comment: Note: there's absolutely no point in naming your structs, if you're going to typedef them. It just clutters the code with a meaningless name, making anyone read the code go "hm ... I wonder what this name is used for?" and then feeling confused when the name isn't found. Yes, I'm projecting, but that doesn't mean I'm wrong.

Comment: @unwind: You are wrong.  If you need to use the struct definition in the body of the struct itself, then you need a name and a typedef.  And that's exactly what he is doing with the _Frag/Frag struct.

Comment: @unwind - the first struct is a linked list, so he has to name it in order for it to have a reference to itself. The second one, not so much.

Comment: So Valgrind found many memory errors in your code, telling you exact locations where problem occurred. I think you can close your question now and start fixing your code. Do not expect other people to fix it for you - it's your call.

Comment: I know, I should fix it for myself. But I have beening debuging for two days, and I have no idea. I don't what to do, I'm in trouble. I want to get some help from others.

Answer (score 10):

You have multiple problems.

Here, you allocate space for 5 chars but copy 6 in (the nul-terminator at the end of the string needs a space, too):

```
  frag->seq = malloc (5 * sizeof (char));
  strcpy (frag->seq, "55555");
```

At the same point, you never set `frag->next` in the second `frag` you allocate.  You need to set it to `NULL`, so that the `while` loop in the `free_frag` routine doesn't run off into the weeds.

The third problem is here:

```
  /* to do : free fragment */
  free (fragment);
```

You free `fragment`, but it's not a whole block recieved from `malloc` - it's just one of the single block of 10 fragments you allocated in one go.  The later `free(frags)` frees that block properly, so you just need to remove that buggy line.

Comment: +1, this combines everybody else's answers into one.  I believe it covers everything you need.

Comment: And for love of all that is holy, please use strdup() for making dynamically allocated copies of strings - then your first bug won't ever happen again.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482375/c-strdup-function

Answer (score 7):

You are attempting to free the middle of your array.

```
Fragment *fragment = &frags[i];
...
...
/* to do : free fragment */
free (fragment);
fragment = NULL;
```

Comment: As a random note, why take an address of a pointer dereference? Why not just use pointer arithmetic? I think `frags + i` is a little clearer than `&frags[i]` but that's just my perspective.

Comment: Well personally I think `&frags[i]` is clearer than `frags + i`, since the first is obviously a pointer to an element of an array just by looking at it.  Without checking other lines of code, `frags + i` could just be an arithmetic expression.  The less context needed to understand an expression the better, in my opinion.  (Think of the questioner's co-worker who has just been told, "Go fix that bug by this afternoon.")

Answer (score 7):

These lines seem to have a *Bufferoverflow*

```
  frag->seq = malloc (5 * sizeof (char));
  strcpy (frag->seq, "55555");
```

Because the string `55555` will also include a terminating zero character that is also written into memory outside the allocated 5 bytes.

Instead you could use `strdup()` which allocates and copies a string

```
  frag->seq = strdup("55555");
```

Comment: It's not causing his problem (directly or indirectly), but it is dangerous indeed.

Comment: `strdup()` is non-standard (unless POSIX is good enough for you), although it's fairly easy to write your own if your OS doesn't provide one.

Answer (score 3):

You're treating `frag_list` as a linked list of `Frag` pointers, but you aren't putting in a terminator when you create the list.

Try this:

```
int
main ()
{
  Fragment *frags = (Fragment *) malloc (10 * sizeof (Fragment));
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      Fragment *fragment = &frags[i];
      fragment->frag_list = (Frag *) malloc (1 * sizeof (Frag));
      Frag *frag = fragment->frag_list;
      frag->seq = malloc (5 * sizeof (char));
      strcpy (frag->seq, "55555");
      frag->next = (Frag *) malloc (1 * sizeof (Frag));
      frag = frag->next;
      frag->seq = malloc (5 * sizeof (char));
      strcpy (frag->seq, "55555");
      frag->next = NULL; // <--------------------- This is what you need to do
    }
  free_frags (frags, 10);
  return 0;
}
```

The issue is that when you `malloc()` a new block of memory, the compiler and/or the OS *might* null it out for you, but more likely it will just give you garbage.  When you try to `free()` that garbage, you get a crash.

Comment: I changed as you said, But there are still some errors. But your tips is right, and I forget that. thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use the *Frag.next* pointer as a sentinel (in free_frags()) then you need to set it to NULL somewhere in your code.

Also, be careful - you're using malloc() to allocate 5 characters for *Frag.seq* and you're copying a non-NULL-terminated string in that space.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a memory address that does not belong to you. This is happening at free_frags() function, specifically at line 41, free (fragment); .