# How to assign a string to a char pointer?

Tags: c++

How to assign a string to a `char*` (char pointer) in C++?

```cpp
char *pw = some string
```

Comment: char* pw = "some string"; Is this not you are expecting?

Comment: if i use like char* pw = "some string"; i am getting exception.
"corruption of heap"

Comment: This is one of those "take a step back" questions. You can't really "assign a string" to a `char *`, because although a `char*` parameter is sometimes referred to as a "string parameter", it isn't actually a string, it's a pointer (to a string). If you're getting heap corruption, then the problem isn't the assignment, the problem is your management of allocated memory. Most likely there's something vital about allocated memory you don't know. Even if this one line could be replaced with a code snippet that stops your program crashing, the important thing is to understand the whole picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For constant initialization you can simply use

```
const char *pw = "mypassword";
```

if the string is stored in a variable, and you need to make a copy of the string then you can use strcpy() function

```
char *pw = new char(strlen(myvariable) + 1);
strcpy(pw, myvariable);
// use of pw
delete [] pw; // do not forget to free allocated memory
```

Comment: You should use `const char *pw` on literals.

Comment: Do I need to free the pw pointer in the first example and if not how does the compiler know when and how to free it.

Comment: The first examples doesn't use dynamic memory, therefore there is no need to free any allocated buffer.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to assign a string literal to `pw`, you can do it like `char *pw = "Hello world";`.

If you have a C++ `std::string` object, the value of which you want to assign to `pw`, you can do it like `char *pw = some_string.c_str()`. However, the value that `pw` points to will only be valid for the life time of `some_string`.

Comment: It's only guranteed to be valid until you perform a mutating operation on `some_string` .

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a `std::string`, you can get a pointer to a C-style string from it, by calling `c_str`. But the pointer needs to be `const`.

```
const char *pw = astr.c_str();
```

If `pw` points to a buffer you've previously allocated, you might instead want to copy the contents of a string into that buffer:

```
astr.copy(pw, lengthOfBuffer);
```

If you're starting with a string literal, it's already a pointer:

```
const char *pw = "Hello, world".
```

Notice the `const` again - string literals should not be modified, as they are compiled into your program.

But you'll have a better time generally if you use `std::string` everywhere:

```
std::string astr("Hello, world");
```

By the way, you need to include the right header:

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to do this:

```
using namespace std;
string someString;
geline(cin,someString);
char *pw = strdup(someString.c_str());
```

But consider doing it another way. Check out http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html (GNU Readline library). I don't know details about it, just heard about it. Others may have more detailed or other tips for reading passwords from standard input.

If you only want to use it for a single call for something you do not need to copy the contents of someString, you may use `someString.c_str()` directly if it is required as `const char *`.

You have to use `free` on `pw` some time later,

Comment: `strdup` is handy but beware of portability issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482375/c-strdup-function

Answer (score 1):

String must be enclosed in double quotes like :

char *pStr = "stackoverflow";

It will store this string literal in the read only memory of the program.
And later on modification to it may cause UB.

Comment: if i use like char* pw = "some string"; i am getting exception. "corruption of heap" – karthik 4 secs ago edit  [delete this comment]

Comment: @Mac - your code works because of C compatibility but it's good practice to use a `const char *`

Comment: Since C++11 this is literally invalid and won't compile. Prior to C++11 it was poor practice & deprecated.