# How to convert a char* pointer into a C++ string?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, strchr

I have a C++ `string`. I need to pass this string to a function accepting a `char*` parameter (for example - `strchr()`).

a) How do I get that pointer?

b) Is there some function equivalent to `strschr()` that works for `C++ strings`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. To get the `C` string equivalent of
   the `C++` `string` object use [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)
   function.
2. To locate the first occurence of a
   `char` in a `string` object use
   [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) function.

Example:

```
string s = "abc";

// call to strlen expects char *
cout<<strlen(s.c_str());  // prints 3

// on failure find_first_of return string::npos
if(s.find_first_of('a') != string::npos)
    cout<<s<<" has an a"<<endl;
else
    cout<<s<<" has no a"<<endl;
```

Note: I gave the `strlen` just an example of a function that takes `char*`.

Comment: @unicornaddict: thanks. now how do I find the other occurrences of that character in the string? [the length of the string is huge, so creating a whole new string is not an option]

Comment: @cambr: There is a **overloaded** version of `find_first_of` which accepts the **position to start the search from** as an argument. I've posted an example here: http://www.ideone.com/bESwL

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly, std:;string has far, far more capabilities than C-style strings. You probably want the [find_first_of()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) method. In general, if you find yourself using the strxxx() functions on C++ std::strings, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Like much of the C++ Standard Library, the string class is a complex beast. To make the most of it, you really need a good reference book. I recommend [The C++ Standard Library](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/index.html), by Nicolai Josuttis.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get a `char*` from a `string`

`string` does not allow you free access to its internal buffer.
The closest you can get is a `const char*` using `.c_str()` if you want it null terminated or `.data()` if it doesn't have to be null terminated.

You can then cast the pointer returned by these functions to `char*` but you do this on your own risk. That being said this is a relatively safe cast to make as long as you make sure you're not changing the string. If you changed it then the pointer you got from `c_str()` may no longer be valid.

This code:

```
string str("Hello World!");
char* sp = (char*)str.c_str();
sp[5] = 'K';
```

is probably ok
However this:

```
string str("Hello World!");
char* sp = (char*)str.c_str();
str = "Chaged string";
sp[5] = 'K';
```

is most definitely not ok.

Comment: +1 for this being the answer to the question _I_ was searching for :)

Comment: More discussion here: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/544209-std-string-c_str-const_cast-char

Answer (score 0):

If str in your string use `str.c_str()` method to get the char* inside it.

Comment: Are you sure it's `c_tsr` and not `c_str`? I'm no C++ expert but I Googled for `c_tsr` and was corrected to `c_str`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to assign a string literal to pw, you can do it like

```
char *pw = "Hello world";
```

If you have a **C++ std::string object**, the value of which you want to assign to **pw**, you can do it like

`char *pw = some_string.c_str()`

However, the value that pw points to will only be valid for the life time of some_string.

> More here :
>   [How to assign a string to char *pw in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235366/how-to-assign-a-string-to-char-pw-in-c)

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: Wrong. c_str() returns a const char *

Comment: This isn't a very good idea.  There's no guarantee that pw will point to the same data at a later point, even if some_string is still around.  It's much safer to call c_str() to each function you need to pass a char*.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string yourString("just an example");
char* charPtr = new char[yourString.size()+1];
strcpy(charPtr, yourString.c_str());
```

Comment: @Neil: it's an example, jeez... but I've edited it for your pleasure ;-)

Comment: You can avoid manual memory management by doing `std::vector<char> charBuf(yourString.begin(), yourString.end()); charBuf.push_back('\0');` - this will let you use `&charBuf[0]` to get a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this exmaple will help you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str ("Replace the vowels in this sentence by asterisks.");
  size_t found;

  found=str.find_first_of("aeiou");
  while (found!=string::npos)
  {
    str[found]='*';
    found=str.find_first_of("aeiou",found+1);
  }

  cout << str << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard provides two member functions of claass std::basic_string that return pointer to the first element of the string. They are `c_str()` and `data()`. But the both return const char *, So you may not use them with a function that has parameter of type char *.

As for function strchr then its first parameter is `const char *`. So you may use c_str() and data() with this function. However it is much better to use member function `find()`of class sttd::basic_string instead of `strchr.`