# How to convert std::string to const char in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I tried to research this for a bit and I can't figure out the problem

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
void choose();
void newuser();
void admuse();

using namespace std;
string x;
string z;
string w;

void CreNeAcc(){


cout << "Enter User Name for your new account\n";
getline(cin, x);

cout << "Enter Password for your new account\n";
getline(cin, z);

cout << "Would you like the account to be admin?\n";
cout << "Yes = Y, No = N\n";
getline(cin, w);
choose();

}

void choose(){

if(w == "Y"){
newuser();
admuse();
}else if(w == "N"){
newuser();
}else{
cout << "Invalide Command\n";
}

}



void newuser(){

const char* Letter_x = x.c_str();
char command [100] = "net user /add ";
strcat(command, x); //This is where I get the error
strcat(command, " ");
strcat(commad, z);
system(command);
}

void admuse(){
    system("new localgroup administrators " << x << " /add")
}
```

also the error its giving me is:

```
cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'char* strcat(char*, const char*)'|
```

Comment: You already have the answer in your question...

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `c_str()` (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)). It's implemented by simply apending it to your `std::string`, like so:

```
string myFavFruit = "Pineapple"
const char* foo = myFavFruit.c_str();
strcat(command, foo);
```

Actually, you have everything there you're just not using your `const char*` variable in the `strcat()`'s arguments. You define `Letter_x`, but then use `x` in the function instead. Rewrite your `newuser()` as follows:

```
void newuser(){

const char* Letter_x = x.c_str();
char command [100] = "net user /add ";
strcat(command, Letter_x); //Here, use 'Letter_x' instead of 'x'
strcat(command, " ");
strcat(command, z); //You will also need to do your 'c_str()' conversion on z before you can use it here, otherwise you'll have the same error as before.
system(command);
}
```

Lastly, you can avoid all this because you can append strings simply using the `+=` operator (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/)). Try this:

```
string command = "net user /add ";
command += x;
command += " ";
command += z;
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to convert a `string` into an `const char*` use `c_str()`.

**On a side note tho:**
why are you using `strcat` in the first place? You can concatenate strings with the `operator+`.

```
string a = "try", b = " this";
string c = a+b; // "try this"
```

Comment: I think it's `c_str()`, right?

Comment: Of course. I had to somehow not press "_". Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for this: [How to convert a char* pointer into a C++ string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707980/how-to-get-a-char-pointer-to-a-c-string)

According to the link, you may use `c_str()` to return a pointer to a null terminated char array version of your string.