# Realloc Invalid Pointer. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

```
     *MyFile.h*

        typedef char* dado_t;
        typedef struct elemento elemento;
        typedef struct lista2 lista2;  

    *MyFile.c*

    struct elemento{
        dado_t str;
        elemento* ant;
        elemento* prox;
    };

    struct lista2{
        elemento* primeiro;
        elemento* ultimo;
        elemento* corrente;
    };

    void_insert(lista2* l, dado_t d){
       elemento* novo = malloc(sizeof(elemento*));
       novo->str = malloc(strlen(d) * sizeof(char));
       novo->str = d;
       l->corrente = novo;
       l->primeiro = novo;
       l->ultimo = novo;
       novo->prox = NULL;
       novo->ant = NULL;

    }

dado_t replace(lista2* l, dado_t d){
   dado_t retorno = malloc(strlen(corrente->str) * sizeof(dado_t));
   retorno = corrente->str;

   corrente->str = realloc(corrente->str, strlen(d) * sizeof(char));
   l->corrente->str = d;
   return retorno;
}
```

Why am I getting this error ? Since `myel->str` is a pointer that has been allocated with `malloc()`. Why the error ?  I'm using an temporary element* to be prevented if an error happen with *realloc()*

Obs:

Comment: you have set `myel->str` to d after the malloc

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, but the error happens before the compiler gets there... =s

Comment: Do you want to share a little more of your code because calling sequence is unclear. perhaps - before realloc - just print myel->str and d - might give some clue

Comment: You cannot assign a string to `myel->str`, you must use `strcpy`. (And reserve space for the zero terminator in your `strlen` line!)

Comment: @Jongware BINGO ! So stupid of me... Thanks guys =)

Comment: If you get it to work, don't hesitate to post the fixed code (or relevant snippet only) as an answer. That way others can see how to repair such an issue as well.

Comment: @Jongware Isnt it better if you post the answer since you gave me that ?

Comment: there seems to be missing all the #include statements that are needed in myfile.c.  I, personally, do not like reverse engineering someone elses' code to determine exactly what is missing.  Please edit the code with the missing statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `dado_t` is a `char *`, which *initially* points to nothing (I mean, not `NULL` but some random value). You correctly allocate some memory for it in

```
novo->str = malloc(strlen(d) * sizeof(char));
```

which has one tiny error: a C string of length `d` needs a single byte more memory for the terminating zero. So change this to

```
novo->str = malloc(strlen(d)+1);
```

Two notes here: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` (I think it's in the specifications; then again, it does no harm, and maybe you want to make sure you have the syntax right when allocating `int`s or other larger types).
Second, most standard libraries have a function that does exactly this: [`strdup`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482375/strdup-function). All you need to do is call it with your string address, it does the +1 part itself.

However, the next line is a more serious error:

```
novo->str = d;
```

In C you cannot "assign" one string to another this way. If you would want to do that, you would assign the *address* of one string to another. Which may lead to unforeseen problems, such as 'assigning' the address a constant string (which is valid but then you cannot modify it), or, worse, a string that is created inside a function on the 'local' stack.

In this case, you want to store a full *copy* of the string `d` from the function's argument, so you would use

```
strcpy (novo->str, d);
```

Do not forget that this pointer will be "lost" if you ever free the structure `novo`. A "lost" pointer is a block of memory that you allocated earlier (in the string `malloc` line) but no longer have a valid variable pointing to. So when freeing your `elemento` lists, call `free(xx->str)` first.

If you make sure that the `str` element is *always* set to `NULL` as soon as you create a new `elemento` structure, you can safely call `free` for the string even though it may be `NULL`; `free` can handle that. As it is, you seem to always assign a value, so it's not a case here, but in general I find it safe to explicitly clear out a newly created structure, for example with `memset (novo, 0, sizeof(elemento));`.

Answer (score 2):

With `elemento* novo = malloc(sizeof(elemento*));` you malloc only space for a pointer but then treat it as space for a struct. That overwrites book keeping information on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Schneider has rightly pointed out that `elemento* novo = malloc(sizeof(elemento*))` only allocates enough room for a pointer (because that’s what `elemento*` is); in this situation there are two common idioms, either of which does fine here:

- `elemento* novo = malloc(sizeof(elemento))`
- `elemento* novo = malloc(sizeof(*novo))`

And of course you need to take Jongware’s advice too!